# Kotlin skip next iteration(s) inside for loop

Tags: kotlin

I need to estimate some portions of data inside loop and I need to skip next portion(s) if first one doesn't meet conditions:

```
val padding = 25
val threshold = 0.1
for (y in 0 until yArr.size) {
    for (x in 0 until xArr.size) {
        val xVal = xArr[x]
        val yVal = yArr[y]
        val subMat = getSubmatrix(yVal - padding, yVal + padding, 
                                  xVal - padding, xVal + padding)

        var out = processSubMatrix(subMat)

        if (x%2 == 1) {
        // do some stuff with array
        } else {
            if(out.max() < threshold) {
                x+=2 // cannot do that because x is immutable
                continue
             } else {
              // do some stuff with array
             }
        }
    }
}
```

In java I can do that with simple construction:

```
for(int x = 0; x < xArr.size; x++) {
    if(someRunTimeCondition) {
        x+=2;
        continue;
    } else { ... }
}
```

So I cannot deside to skip some of iterations on Range initialization step (before I come inside loop). Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a simple solution but you could always use a `while` loop and do the incrementing yourself.

```
var x = 0
while (x < xArr.size) {
    ...
    x++
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do that in "for" loop?

Comment: I didn't say that. Just that this is a way to achieve your goal. I wouldn't know if it is possible off the top of my head.